# java web app: custom parameter

Tags: java

In a java project, it can simply place some init parameter in a `.property` file or `.xml` file, both of which is placed in disk file system, along with application. What if I want to place those custom parameter in a database, along with business data? Should it save `.property` or `.xml` file directly into database?

Comment: Is your question if you should piece the file apart into tables and columns, or use it "as is" as a CLOB in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, and it depends on the database you use (consider an xml database), anyway the most common are ther elationsal databases whcih enable you to save information as a binary objects (as a blob).

Any way its possible the question is if you need this or not, init parameters envolve often information about the database access , if this is true in your case this will not be relevant since you will not be able to access the database.

Some local information base is pretty important, imagine you need to know on start up which server you need to access (where your database is) this is something you will still need to keep localy (as a property file or in the registry which is an option too to save your init parameters)